# Compare a form input with a regex expression

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, frameworks

I am using Laravel Auth to make authentication. I need to compare a field input (Phone Number) with a regex expression in validator method. How can I do this. Below is the method code I am using,

(Currently I am hard coding my number "0312 1234567" How can I use a regex expression here?)

```php
public function validator(array $data)
{ 
    if($data['emailOrNumber'] == "03121234567") {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'emailOrNumber' => ['required', 'numeric','unique:usersNew,phone'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8'],
            'surname2' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255']
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have not hard coded your number, you just have check the number.

Comment: @TharakaDilshan I want to check the input data with a regex expression in if condition. Any idea how can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to check if the string contains only numbers? You can use the ```is_numeric``` php function in that case. It works with leading zeros, but also with leading ```+``` and ```-```, which might lead to some bugs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check against a regex, you can use the Regex validation rule.

You could use

```
return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'emailOrNumber' => ['required', 'numeric','unique:usersNew,phone', 'regex:/(\+[0-9]{2})?[0-9]{10,12}/g'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8'],
            'surname2' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255']
        ]);
```

Little hint, I wouldn't save the email or phone number in the same column in the database. These are two completely different things, so I would save them in differrent columns. You can always leave on of the two columns empty.

You can read more about this validation on https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-regex

Comment: Thanks @tim but we cant use a regex inside validator that has pipe lines. We have to make a separate array for that regex. isnt this?